# NSDate as argument in customMethod

Tags: iphone, methods, ios5, nsdate

I've defined my custom method ( `-(void)loadXML {}` ) into my appDelegate.
Now I'd like to use it in severals viewControllers; Right now I'm using local NSDate objects.

```
    NSDate *todayDate = [NSDate date];
    NSString *XMLUrl = @"http://localhost/MyApp/GetXML?&aDate=";
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", XMLUrl, todayDate];
    tbxml = [[TBXML alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
```

instead of 'todayDate' I'd like to have 'selectedDate'; also how I add a bool to my method, need to have some conditions into my method?

Comment: How do you store your 'selectedDate'? And about a 'boot' ... what do you mean? ..you want to invoke your method when the application starts?

Comment: `-(void)loadXML:(NSDate*)selectedDate{}` ??

Comment: @makaron: sorry, I've typed wrong, I meant bool not boot; right now my app invokes an method that parses an xml by todayDate but I'm using (Si-Calendar)[https://github.com/voidparadox/Si-Calendar] and want to parse the xml by selected date from calendar

Comment: @el.severo probably means `BOOL`; and s/he ought to learn how to use a NSDateFormatter. Constructing a string the way it's being done up there looks like something that could be easily broken.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann: you're right; I've convert my `NSDate` object to a string; what about the `BOOL`? and my app crashes at lunching...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you can do:

```
NSDate *selectedDate = ???????; // set this to whatever you want selectedDate to be
BOOL myBoolean = YES;
NSDateFormatter * dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[dateFormat setDateFormat: @"yyyy-MM-dd"]; // or whatever format you wish
NSString *urlString = 
    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://localhost/MyApp/GetXML?BOOL=%@&aDate=%@", 
    (myBoolean ? @"YES" : @"NO"), 
    [dateFormatter stringFromDate: selectedDate]];

tbxml = [[TBXML alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[dateFormatter release]; // don't forget to release, if not using ARC
```

And for your benefit, I'm showing you how to use a [NSDateFormatter](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and a [generic C ternary conditional](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F%3a).

I hope this helps you out!

Comment: calling my loadXML method in didFinishLunchingWithOptions [here's the example](http://pastie.org/private/g5lpjuoobzdxgvbvbh8y4a) crashes my app

Comment: get rid of the `autorelease` after alloc'ing and init'ing your date formatter.